# Selenium: does browsermob can work on RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: selenium, httprequest

i am trying to use browsermob for manipulating http request,  but I found it seems not working on remote mode, any one has any idea on this? appreciates!

it is working fine locally 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities)

but actually on our working environment, we always run the case on a remote server,like this:
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://d-sjc-00517444.corp.com:4444/wd/hub"),capability);

then firefox cannot open the page said:

The proxy server is refusing connections
Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections.
Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct.
Contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working on remote mode". Do you have details?

Comment: What are you doing and how are you doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using `Selenium Grid`.

You have to start `Browsermob Proxy API` on the machine which is the `HUB` of your grid.
Like this you can perform all the required `REST API` calls described on [this](https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy) page.

Answer (score 0):

Plain guessing:

- Your application can be behind firewall, so if you are testing it via webdriver, you are inside intranet and if you do it remotely, you can face issues, that the app cannot be found outside the internet
- You do something when initializing the ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver

But without details, its almost impossible to provide any solution

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `Selenium Grid` is running on `http://d-sjc-00517444.corp.com:4444`, but your Java client is running on another machine.

I guess you code sets the proxy on WebDriver likes this:

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
```

*This will cause Browser to forward all requests to the proxy running on Browser's machine, not your Java client's machine.*

**On the machine where Selenium is running**

- Start proxy server (on the machine where Selenium is running)

  ```
  sh browsermob-proxy -port 9090
  ```
- Start proxy

  ```
  curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/proxy
  {"port":9091}
  ```